# Space of inscribed $n$-gons modulo projective transformations.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Say $P \sim Q$ ($P$ and $Q$ are «projectively equivalent») iff there is a projective transformation $f$ such that $f(P) = Q$.  Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.  I read that the space of inscribed $n$-gons modulo projective equivalence has dimension $n-3$.  Why is this?  Also, are there any related results?

Comment: What is an "inscribed n-gon"?  Inscribed in a circle?

Comment: Sorry, I mean inscribed in a conic.

Comment: Conic or circle doesn't make a difference (projectively), but it does matter what you mean by an N-gon.  Here it means "an ordered set of N distinct points".  Other meanings change the space of polygons, though its dimension is (N-3) under any interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the projective transformations fixing a conic, there is a unique one sending any given ordered triple of points to any other given ordered triple of points.  So you are free to determine the location of the first 3 vertices of the n-gon, modulo projective equivalence, but any two placements of the remaining (n-3) points are projectively inequivalent.

Thus, the space of n-gons up to projective equivalence can be thought of as the space of (n-3) points on a projective line (or conic, it is isomorphic) punctured at three given points.  This has dimension (n-3).